# onMessageReceived in android O not called when app in background

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-8.0-oreo

I am sending data payload notifications from my server. here is example:

```
url= "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"
{
  "to" : "userToken",
  "data" : {
    //some json here
  }
}
```

in such way i am successfully sending messages to users, even if app isn't running, in all pre Android O devices.
But on Android O device, onMessageReceived not called when app is not launched...

is there some new rules in O ? how it can be fixed? thanks!

**UPDATES**

This question is not about notifications, but about firebase message srvice!

Anyway, chanels for Android O is also implemented:

```
val CHANEL_ID = "MY_CHANEL_ID"

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    val channel = NotificationChannel(CHANEL_ID, "Channel human readable title", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
    (getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager).createNotificationChannel(channel)
}
```

Comment: have you declared the service class in manifest ??

Comment: sure.
other (pre O) devices successfully receive this messages

Comment: have you find any solution for this?

Comment: @dakshbhatt21
it looks like the problem was in my one plus hydrogen beta. when I drop it and make total refresh of the phone - it works ok.

Comment: @AndriyAntonov ok great, will try that too and will post the update

Comment: @dakshbhatt21 have you try it already?

Comment: @AndriyAntonov  did you found the solution for this  issue .  I have found that with usign JobSheduler  we can do background tasks but i don't know how to do it . 
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

If app is killed in android O  it not allow background process of the app to be run ,  I also facing this issue if you have found some solution then please let me know .

Answer (score 0):

you need to create the notification channel before it can be used.

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

      /* Create or update. */
      NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("my_channel_01",
          "Channel human readable title", 
          NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
      mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
  }
```

Also you need to use channels only if your targetSdkVersion is 26 or higher.

If you are using NotificationCompat.Builder, you also need to update to the beta version of the support library: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#26-0-0-beta2 (to be able to call setChannelId on the compat builder).

Be careful as this library update raises minSdkLevel to 14.

Comment: thanks, but i chanels already implemented. but still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

> Starting in Android 8.0 (API level 26), notification channels allow
>   you to create a user-customizable channel for each type of
>   notification you want to display. Notification channels provide a
>   unified system to help users manage notifications. When you target
>   Android 8.0 (API level 26), you must implement one or more
>   notification channels to display notifications to your users. If you
>   don't target Android 8.0 (API level 26) but your app is used on
>   devices running Android 8.0 (API level 26), your app behaves the same
>   as it would on devices running Android 7.1 (API level 25) or lower.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#ManageChannels

**Sample Code:**

```
        // The id of the channel.
        String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this).setChannel(CHANNEL_ID)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle("My notification")
                        .setContentText("Hello World!");
        // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
        // started Activity.
        // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
        // your app to the Home screen.
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                        0,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // mNotificationId is a unique integer your app uses to identify the
        // notification. For example, to cancel the notification, you can pass its ID
        // number to NotificationManager.cancel().
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention this: channel is already implemented, but still not work...

Answer (score -1):

it looks like the problem was in my one plus hydrogen beta. when I drop it and make total refresh of the phone - it works ok.