# FCM push notifications are not appearing in background in android 8.0 Oreo device

Tags: firebase, push-notification, ionic2, android-8.0-oreo, cordova-plugin-fcm

I've installed and configured all the requirements of FCM on client and server(node-fcm) both and sending push notification successfully whenever I want in all devices, but when I'm sending to Android 8.0 device its coming within app when app is opened while not coming in background when app is closed. Kindly anyone who can help me in this or tell if FCM has updates for oreo or not, or this is a bug.
Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47617989/onmessagereceived-in-android-o-not-called-when-app-in-background

Comment: https://github.com/NativeScript/push-plugin/issues/141

Comment: anyone cane answer me relevant to ionic2